# use nokogiri 1.5.9 with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I want to use Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails, but when I run `bundle install` I get this error:

```
Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

nokogiri 1.6.0 does not support Ruby <1.9.2.

I tried installing nokogiri 1.5.9 to make things work but it did not help.

Comment: You probably have a gem that requires nokogiri 1.6+; you'll have to identify it and replace or downgrade it so that it doesn't bring nokogiri 1.6+ along as a dependency.

Comment: What version of Rails? And what extra gems?

Comment: i am using rails 3.2.3 and gems used are 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'; 'rspec-rails','2.9.0';'sass-rails','3.2.4';'coffee-rails', '3.2.2';'uglifier', '1.2.3';'jquery-rails', '~>2.0.0';'capybara', '1.1.2'; '0.12.2'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i added the line

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5.10'
```

in my Gemfile and it install nokogiri 1.5.10 and the bundle install succeeded !

Answer (score -1):

According to the [changelog](http://nokogiri.org/CHANGELOG_rdoc.html):

```
1.5.0 beta1 / 2010/05/22
Ruby 1.8.6 is deprecated. Nokogiri will install, but official support is ended.
```

So, you'll probably need to use nokogirl version 1.4.7.